# How to transcode PHP uploaded videos into multiple qualities

Tags: php, video, html5-video, transcoding

Im making a video streaming site, for users to upload videos, the uploads are processed via PHP. I just bought some code for a videojs player with a quality changer thingy, but looking at the code it seems like the code only changes the source of the video meaning that i would need to host like 4 files for each video, one for each quality. 
My question being that, how can i have the videos uploaded automatically transcoded into multiple files with different resolutions?

my html reference:

```
<video id="video_1" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="https://myvideosource.webm.720p.webm" type="video/webm" label="720P">
    <source src="https://myvideosource.webm.480p.webm" type="video/webm" label="480P" selected="true">
    <source src="https://myvideosource.webm.360p.webm" type="video/webm" label="360P">
    <source src="https://myvideosource.webm.240p.webm" type="video/webm" label="240P">
</video>
```

Comment: Transcode it with ffmpeg, or use a service to transcode it.

Comment: Yeah, try https://ffmpeg.org if you can install it (or already have it) on your server. You can then use something like https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg to use it with PHP to recode your uploaded videos.